# RabbitMQ: override routing key

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am wondering if there there is a way to override the routing key once the message gets to the broker.

For an example: there are 2 Rabbit servers. A message is sent to the first server and the RabbitMQ sets the routing key to s1. If it's sent to the second server the routing key is set to s2.

I don't want the producer to worry about the routing key. Can it be set or overridden once the message gets to the broker?

Can RabbitMQ be setup this way or is there a plugin that enables this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean.

> and the RabbitMQ sets the routing key to s1

The RabbitMQ does not **set the routing key**, the client does.

The routing key is used by the broker to route to a specific queue; it **has** to be set by the producer; it's part of the API

```
void basicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, BasicProperties props, byte[] body) throws IOException;
```